# How to create Field Collection Item by code in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

How to create a Field Collection item for a node by program in Drupal 8. I have tried with below code, but it doesn't work. 'field_abc_inside' is the field of the Field Collection 'field_abc'.

```
$field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array(
            'field_name' => 'field_abc',
            'field_abc_inside' => array('value'=> 'Test data'),
        )); 
$field_collection_item->setHostEntity($node);
$field_collection_item->save();
```

Comment: Found the answer myself on '8.x-1.0-alpha1' version.  $entity = FieldCollectionItem::create(['field_name' => 'field_abc']);  
$entity->field_abc_inside->setValue('Test data');  
$entity->setHostEntity($node);  
$entity->save();

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->getAccount()->id();
$user = User::load($user_id);

$fc = FieldCollectionItem::create(array(
     "field_name" => "field_hobbies",
));

$fc->set('field_hobby_name', 'Watch TV');
$fc->setHostEntity($user);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

That code helped me but I have one observation.

\Drupal::currentUser() is the user object, which is clear since it is using it to retrieve the id().
Therefore no need to User::load() it again in line 2, redundant processing that will cause the function to take longer to run.

```
// Get the current user object
$user = \Drupal::currentUser();

// Prepare the new Field Collection Item object
$fc = FieldCollectionItem::create(array(
     "field_name" => "field_hobbies",
));

// Sets more field values
$fc->set('field_hobby_name', 'Watch TV');
// Sets the host record; where the field collection will be attached into
$fc->setHostEntity($user);
// Saves it into an actual field collection record
$fc->save();
```